# Follow up: how to plot a function under NDSolve domain

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

Here is the details of the code to plot.

```
Clear[x, y, ψ1, ψ2, ψ3, ψ4, eqn, eqnWithInitial,v, j];
eqn = Thread[
       I D[{ψ1[x, y, t], ψ2[x, y, t], ψ3[x, y, t], ψ4[
            x, y, t]}, 
          t] == {v (-I D[ψ3[x, y, t], x] - D[ψ3[x, y, t], y]) + 
          2 Δ ψ4[x, y, t], 
         v (-I D[ψ4[x, y, t], x] - D[ψ4[x, y, t], y]), 
         v (-I D[ψ1[x, y, t], x] + D[ψ1[x, y, t], y]), 
         v (-I D[ψ2[x, y, t], x] + D[ψ2[x, y, t], y]) + 
          2 Δ ψ1[x, y, t]}];
eqnWithInitial = 
      Join[eqn, 
       Thread[{ψ1[x, y, 0], ψ2[x, y, 0], ψ3[x, y, 
           0], ψ4[x, y, 0]} == {1, 1, 1, 
           1} (x + I*y) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]], 
       Thread[{ψ1[-5, y, t], ψ2[-5, y, t], ψ3[-5, y, 
           t], ψ4[-5, y, t]} == {ψ1[5, y, t], ψ2[5, y, 
           t], ψ3[5, y, t], ψ4[5, y, t]}], 
       Thread[{ψ1[x, -5, t], ψ2[x, -5, t], ψ3[x, -5, 
           t], ψ4[x, -5, t]} == {ψ1[x, 5, t], ψ2[x, 5, 
           t], ψ3[x, 5, t], ψ4[x, 5, t]}]];

v = 1;
Δ = 1;
tMax = 8;

solution = 
      First @ NDSolve[
        eqnWithInitial, {ψ1[x, y, t], ψ2[x, y, t], ψ3[x, y,
           t], ψ4[x, y, t]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {t, 0, tMax}, 
        Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
          "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
            "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];

Ψ1[x_, y_, t_] = ψ1[x, y, t] /. solution;
Ψ2[x_, y_, t_] = ψ2[x, y, t] /. solution;
Ψ3[x_, y_, t_] = ψ3[x, y, t] /. solution;
Ψ4[x_, y_, t_] = ψ4[x, y, t] /. solution; 

myrotorz1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] = 
  I/2 * (-Conjugate[D[Ψ1[x, y, t], y]] * D[Ψ1[x, y, t], x] + 
    D[Ψ1[x, y, t],y] * Conjugate[D[Ψ1[x, y, t], x]] + 
    Conjugate[D[Ψ1[x, y, t], x]] * D[Ψ1[x, y, t], y] - 
    D[Ψ1[x, y, t], x] * Conjugate[D[Ψ1[x, y, t], y]]);
```

Here is something that may be reasonable as R. M. suggested

```
NIntegrate[myrotorz1[x, y, 0], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},Method -> "Trapezoidal"]

(Debug) During evaluation of In[18]:= NIntegrate::ncvi: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 iterated refinements in y in the region {{-5.,5.},{-5.,5.}}. NIntegrate obtained 0.012104690946256463` and 0.8391566465710514` for the integral and error estimates. >>

(Debug) Out[18]= 0.0121047
```

My point is to plot for `myrotorz1[x, y, t]` as a function of `t` but takes too much time. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
Plot[NIntegrate[myrotorz1[x, y, t], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},Method -> "Trapezoidal"], {t, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) to the [pitfalls question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393). -- The hint contained in the error message is that the symbols `x` and `y` do not have numerical values.

Comment: Your definition for `myrotorz1` is has syntax errors. Perhaps this is because of an error introduced in transferring your code to this site, but it needs to corrected before we can help you further.

Comment: @m_goldberg, you are right. I have made the correction.

Comment: I don't get the error you indicated in the first post.  I get only `NIntegrate::slwcon` (slow convergence).  I'm using V10.2. -- **What error are *you* getting?**

Comment: @MichaelE2 slow convergence plus suppressed the output

Comment: I get a plot. Here is a proof of concept: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ8k1.png -- Your original command will take much longer than I have to spend (please pardon me). I don't see how the output can be suppressed unless you added a semi-colon or the kernel crashed. Note that integrating expressions built on `InterpolatingFunction` usually converge slowly.

Comment: Other possibilities: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77359#77359, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73339#73339 -- Or this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVMMu.png, but at 9-12 sec. per integration, plotting stil takesl prohibitively long.

Comment: @MichaelE2, i use V8,I couldn't see any plot when I try your comments.

Comment: I don't have access to V8, and I can't recall anything relevant that might be different.  Sorry, I can't be more help.  Because of the difference, you probably should add the version information to your question.  Or upgrade ;-)

Comment: @MichaelE2, this is the error I get:NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand 1000000 Re[myrotorz1[x,y,0.003003]] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-5,5},{-5,5}}. >>

Comment: Try changing `myrotorz1`'s definition as `myrotorz1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ]` and probably also for all the `Ψ` and see if that helps.

Comment: @R.M., ok I will check & let you know.

Comment: @R.M still running

Comment: @R.M.I get a result for (Debug) In[18]:= NIntegrate[
 myrotorz1[x, y, 0], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"]

(Debug) During evaluation of In[18]:= NIntegrate::ncvi: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 iterated refinements in y in the region {{-5.,5.},{-5.,5.}}. NIntegrate obtained 0.012104690946256463` and 0.8391566465710514` for the integral and error estimates. >>

(Debug) Out[18]= 0.0121047

Comment: @R.M. when I try to plot using Plot[NIntegrate[myrotorz1[x, y, t], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},  Method -> "Trapezoidal"], {t, 0, 4}] takes too much!

Comment: @MichaelE2, I checked your suggestion but I wasn't able to make a plot. I use V8.

Comment: As I said, I don't have V8 and I don't have any more suggestions at this point.  Sorry.  If I think of something I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much can be said without knowing the form of myrotorz1[x, y, t]
I would first include NumericQ to the function. But for a simple function you can do it easily. Considering a simple function, I will do the following.

```
f[x_, y_, t_] := x^2 + y^2 + t^2
data[t_] := NIntegrate[f[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
toplot = ParallelTable[data[t], {t, 0, 10}] // ListPlot
```

Comment: it's a follow up question and given on the link above.